# how to make django form override model?

Tags: django, django-forms

In a django model, I have a field

```
state = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

And I want to keep this max length of 100 in the model and database. But when I display an html form, I want to limit its maxlength to 2.

I do this:

```
class EditMyThingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyThing
        fields = [ 'state' ]
        widgets = { 'state': forms.TextInput(attrs={'maxlength': 2}) }
```

But no matter what I do, maxlength is 100! Does the Form seriously not override the Model?

Comment: When you say `no matter what I do, maxlength is 100`, are you talking about the actual html output or the form validation?

Comment: What HTML does `{{ form }}` render?

Comment: actual html had maxlength=100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to override it like this :)

```
from django import forms


class EditMyThingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    state = forms.CharField(label='State', widget=forms.Textarea, max_length=2)

    class Meta:
        model = MyThing
        fields = ('state', )
```